# looping through a dictionary and printing it in a certain format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
# a small DB of people who stole my books

dic = {
'Cohen'     : 'Calvino' 'Evertt' 'Borges',
'Larry'     : 'The Bible', 
'Volanski'  : 'Phone Book'
}

# here's an abortive attempt to print it in a CSV format
for k in dic.keys():
    print (k, '\t')
for v in dic.keys():
    print (dic[v], ' ')
```

**This is the the ugly output:**

```
Volanski    
Phone Book  
CalvinoEverttBorges  
The Bible  
Cohen   
Phone Book  
CalvinoEverttBorges  
The Bible  
Larry   
Phone Book  
CalvinoEverttBorges  
The Bible
```

**This is how I wished the output to look like:**

```
Cohen      Larry       Volanski  
Calvino    The Bible   Phone Book  
Evertt  
Borgest
```

(only tab-separated which I didn't manage to show here)

Comment: yes, this is how i wanted it to look like ;) thanks, Felix!

Comment: First of all, use list, like `['Calvino', 'Evertt', 'Borges']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work out neater formatting

```
dic = {'Cohen'     : ['Calvino', 'Evertt', 'Borges'],
       'Larry'     : ['The Bible'],
       'Volanski'  : ['Phone Book']}

# Get max name size
mx_nm_len = len(max(dic,key=len))
mx_bk_len = max([len(max(books, key=len)) for books in dic.itervalues()])

# Store max name size + 1
mx = max([mx_nm_len, mx_bk_len]) + 1

# Store people
keys = dic.keys()

# Create generic format code to print neat list
fmat = ("%-"+str(mx)+"s")*len(keys)

# Print header line
print fmat % tuple(keys)

# similar to zip command but works for any number of lists
# Assumes all dic.values() are lists
# "zips" to longest list and uses None when any given list runs out of values
books = map(None, *dic.values())

# replaces None values in row outputs with empty strings and prints result using
# string format code (fmat)
for row in books:
    row = tuple([book if book!= None else "" for book in row])
    print fmat % row
```

Comment: that's very neat, and thank you so much for the comments, otherwise I wouldn't have understood the code!

Comment: No problem glad its helpful. The "trickiest" bit is my use of the map function. Added more comments to help explain its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
dic = {
   'Cohen'     : ['Calvino', 'Evertt', 'Borges'],
   'Larry'     : ['The Bible'],
   'Volanski'  : ['Phone Book']
}


ordered = []
maxlen = 0

for k in sorted(dic.keys()):
    lst = [k] + dic[k]
    maxlen = max(len(lst), maxlen)
    ordered.append(iter(lst))

for i in range(maxlen):
    print "\t".join(next(j, '') for j in ordered)
```

Comment: Dictionary keys should probably be sorted, python does not guarantee sort order. You can do this cleaner with itertools, but then again miss all the fun and understanding :D

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you didn't define the data in the right way to begin with. The way you've defined the first entry is understood by Python in precisely the way it's printed: a single string. If you want multiple elements, you need to define your elements as containing multiple elements:

```
dic = {
  'Cohen'     : ['Calvino', 'Evertt', 'Borges'],
  'Larry'     : ['The Bible'], 
  'Volanski'  : ['Phone Book']
}
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    print "%s\t%s" % (key, "\t".join(value))
```

**Edit** OK, didn't see you wanted the names across the top and titles downwards. A bit trickier, but this will do it:

```
import itertools
print "\t".join(dic.keys())
for books in itertools.izip_longest(*dic.values(), fillvalue=''):
    print "\t".join(books)
```

Comment: I see. But the output looks is formatted now in rows, not in columns:      Volanski Phone Book     
Cohen Calvino Evertt Borges     
Larry The Bible

Comment: Good solution, but empty rows cause a shift... Using `ljust` might be good with a fixed padding evaluated from longest string in the values...

Comment: @fraxel the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) give a guarantee that if the dictionary is not modified between accesses, they will give the same order: "If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond."

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - many thanks, I didn't know that, very useful to know (but potentially a little dangerous...)

Answer (score 0):

This solution ensures the output is sorted and items wind up in the correct columns. I use `expandtabs()` to set the tab length, to make it pretty print.

```
import itertools

dic = {'Cohen':['Calvino', 'Evertt','Borges'],'Larry': ['The Bible'], 'Volanski'  :['Phone Book']}

sorted_keys = sorted(dic.keys())
for name in sorted_keys:
    print (name+'\t').expandtabs(15),
print
zippp = list(itertools.izip_longest(*[dic[i] for i in sorted_keys]))
for i in xrange(len(zippp[0])):
    for j in xrange(len(zippp)):
        if zippp[i][j]:
            print (zippp[i][j]+'\t').expandtabs(15),
    print
```

Produces:

```
Cohen           Larry           Volanski       
Calvino         The Bible       Phone Book     
Evertt         
Borges
```